# Rake assets:precompile issue. parsing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I am getting an issue, while precompile assets in production env.

```
AssetSync: using default configuration from built-in initializer
rake aborted!
Caught Encoding::CompatibilityError at '["ok","/*!\n * jQuery': incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)
  (in /home/rails_work/bunk1_dev/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@bunk1/gems/json_pure-1.7.6/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:242:in `rescue in parse_string'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@bunk1/gems/json_pure-1.7.6/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:213:in `parse_string'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@bunk1/gems/json_pure-1.7.6/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:257:in `parse_value'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@bunk1/gems/json_pure-1.7.6/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:121:in `parse'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@bunk1/gems/json_pure-1.7.6/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse`
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue, this issue is related to json_pure gem precompilation. Just remove "require 'json/pure'" from the code and apply "require 'json'". Hope the answer would help others.

Thanks